# data.frame into structure(list())

Tags: r, list, dataframe, structure

How can I transform a data.frame in my workspace into a `structure(list())`-form like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484218/how-to-find-index-between-two-set-of-strings) in order to share it with this community. Always been asking this myself.

Let's take the built-in dataframe `mtcars`.

Thank you.

Comment: `dput()` which deparses the object

Comment: This question is a subset of [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). See the accepted answer, for example.